# Why this URLClassLoader sometimes works and sometimes doesn't?

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

I have a quite complex Java software that must load dynamically a class, create an object and invoke one of its methods. It turns out that in some situations this raises a `NoClassDefFoundError` (caused by a `ClassNotFoundException`) if the loaded class refers another one.

Say we have:

```
public interface Go {
    void go();
}
```

Say that the class to be loaded is:

```
package foo;
import static baz.Baz.BAZ;
public class Foo implements Go {
    @Override
    void go() { 
        ...
        something = BAZ;
        ...
    }
}
```

where

```
package baz;
public class Baz {
    public static final int BAZ = 111;
    ...
}
```

Say that the class is loaded this way:

```
try (final URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url })) {
    final Class<? extends Foo> clazz =  
        loader.loadClass("foo.Foo").asSubclass(Go.class);
    this.obj = clazz.newInstance();
    this.obj.go();
} catch ...
```

Then everything works. Say that instead you do things this other way:

```
try (final URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url })) {
    final Class<? extends Foo> clazz =  
        loader.loadClass("foo.Foo").asSubclass(Go.class);
    this.obj = clazz.newInstance();
    //we do not invoke go() now...
} catch ...

//later, in another method...
this.obj.go();
```

Now the invocation of `go()` raises a `NoClassDefFoundError`, complaining it cannot load `baz.Baz`. Of course the url is the same. Of course both `foo.Foo` and `baz.Baz` are in the path indicated by `url`. The only difference I can see is the moment when the `go()` method is invoked.

What is wrong here?

Comment: There is some information missing : which package is Go in? What is the URL being passed to the URLClassloader? And does the compiler accept the loading of Foo as subclass Go and then assigning it to ```? extends Foo``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong here?

I think that the problem is this:

```
try (final URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url })) {
```

That will cause the classloader to be closed when you exit the try block.  The `close()` method's [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#close--) says:

> Closes this URLClassLoader, so that it can no longer be used to load new classes or resources that are defined by this loader.

Calling the `go()` method is triggering class initialization for the `Go` class, and that is what is causing the `Baz` class to be loaded and initialized.  If the latter class loading occurs after the classloader has been closed, it is going to fail.

Answer (score 1):

If a class depends on other classes, these are *lazily loaded*.

That means loading `foo.FOO` does not load `baz.BAZ` at the same time. The latter is loaded when it is first accessed. In your case, the method call to `go()` also loads it.

In your second example, at the time when the method `go()` is called, the `URLClassLoader` is already *closed* - by the try-with-resources statement. Hence, it cannot load classes anymore.